# Android Studio, Firebase - List error

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get an author of post from List and I'm getting error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1
```

Program always gives me index which equals -1
Here is the code from which it gets error:

```
@Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(mCurrentUser.getUid())){

                mDatabasePosts.orderByKey().equalTo(dataSnapshot.getKey()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                            if(mPostModelList.size() == 1) {
                                mPostModelList.clear();
                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }else if(mPostModelList.size() > 1){
                                Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);

                                //mPostModelList.remove(post);

                                /* ERROR -----> */ String p = mPostModelList.get(mPostModelList.indexOf(post)).getDesc(); // <----- ERROR

                                Toast.makeText(mView.getContext(), p, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you fire a query in this line:

```
mDatabasePosts.orderByKey().equalTo(dataSnapshot.getKey())...
```

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. So the snapshot resulting from this query contains a list of those results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result. And your listener doesn't handle the fact that it gets a list.

But in this case you don't even need a query. That first line is the equivalent to:

```
mDatabasePosts.child(dataSnapshot.getKey())...
```

This does a direct lookup of the child node, instead of firing a query. Not only is this guaranteed to have only a single result, it is also going to be faster (since the server doesn't need to do a query for it). And a third advantage: the `dataSnapshot` passed to your callback will just contain the single snapshot, so you won't need to loop. Your current code will just work.

Answer (score 0):

`mPostModelList.indexOf(post)` will return -1 if `post` is not found in the list.

If you are sure **post object** exists in that **list** and still not getting correct index, then you need to override **equals() & hashCode()** method in Post class and add your logic there to make sure it is same

e.g. Sample **Post** class using **id** field

```
public class Post {
    public String id;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return super.equals(((Post)obj).id.equals(this.id));
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id.hashCode();
    }
}
```